# Inline datacontext without a Using statement

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

It would be nice to use this one line:

```
    results = (From t In New MyDataContext().MyTable Select t ...
```

instead of this:

```
Using context As New MyDataContext
    results = (From t In context.MyTable Select t...
End Using
```

but `Dispose` does not get called. What are the issues in using the first method?

Comment: Dispose will get called when the GC gets around to it. A LINQ-to-SQL datacontext will (IIRC) open and close the connection around each query.. So there shouldn't be much of an impact at all.

Comment: First method has issues with maintainability.

Comment: Using the first method, the context immediately goes out of scope.  May or may not be an issue depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: what issues with maintainability?

Comment: I'm fine with disposing when GC gets around to it. and in this case I don't need the context again, good to know I can reduce the 3 lines to the one.